# How to change the nested itemize bullet characters?

Tags: formatting, lists, itemize, nesting

When creating a nested `itemize` environment in LaTeX as follows:

```
\begin{itemize} 
\item one \dots{}
     \begin{itemize} 
        \item Language Models
        \item Vector Space Models
     \end{itemize}
\item two \dots{}
\item three \dots{}
\end{itemize}
```

I have tried to change the inner item characters by adding the following line after line 3

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\star$}
```

Nothing changes!

However, if it is only one "not nested", it works just fine as in the following:

```
\begin{itemize} 
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\star$}
\item one \dots{}
\item two \dots{}
\item three \dots{}
\end{itemize}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Without any package, the correct command to be redefined is `\labelitemii` (note the second `i`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\star$}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize} 
\item one \dots{}
     \begin{itemize} 
        \item Language Models
        \item Vector Space Models
     \end{itemize}
\item two \dots{}
\item three \dots{}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Stating the obvious : the number of `i` denotes the item level. `i` = first level, `ii` = second level, etc.

Comment: Not "etc." unfortunately - it seems to stop at `iii`. No `iiii`: `! LaTeX Error: \labelitemiiii undefined.` :-/

Comment: ```\labelitemiv``` is what you're looking for - ie, using roman numerals

Answer (score 51):

If you use [the `enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/) you can easily reset the label via `[label=$\star$]` option.

If this is the default behavior you want for nested lists you can use `\setlist[itemize,2]{label={$\star$}}` to automatically set the 2nd level `itemize` lists to use the `\star`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize} 
\item one \dots{}
     \begin{itemize}[label=$\star$]
        \item Language Models
        \item Vector Space Models
     \end{itemize}
\item two \dots{}
\item three \dots{}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning enumitem.

Comment: And for those who don't want a star: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42805/what-are-original-itemize-bullet-definitions

Comment: @ZachSmith: You can change the value given to `label=` if you want something other than a star. See for instance [How to represent cross and tick in itemize bullets?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48036/4301).