# How to represent cross and tick in itemize bullets?

Tags: symbols, itemize

I have a an `itemize` environment in LaTeX. How can I represent a **tick** and a **cross** symbol instead of a dot?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) you can use `label={}` to specify it on a per instance basis, or use `\setlist[itemize,<n>]{label=<symbol>}` to set it based on the nesting level, where:
`<symbol>` is to be used at the given nesting level `<n>`:

[image]

Here I have used the `\checkmark` from [the `amsfonts` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts/), but you can use any symbol you like.

### References:

- If you need depper lists see [A five level deep list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41408/a-five-level-deep-list/41409#41409).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\times$}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=$\checkmark$}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=$\diamond$}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=$\bullet$}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$}]
    \item foo
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[label={\checkmark}]
    \item bar
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
    \item foo
    \begin{itemize}
        \item bar
        \begin{itemize}
            \item abc
            \begin{itemize}
                \item def
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
    \item bar
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

---

Without the `enumitem` package you could use `\renewcommand{\labelitem<n>}{<symbol>}` to redefine the marker, where `<n>` is a roman numeral (`i`, `ii`, `iii`, or `iv`) representing the nesting depth of `itemize`.  The following yields a similar result to above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\begin{itemize}
    \item foo
\end{itemize}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\checkmark$}
\begin{itemize}
    \item bar
\end{itemize}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\times$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\checkmark$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\diamond$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$\bullet$}
\begin{itemize}
    \item foo
    \begin{itemize}
        \item bar
        \begin{itemize}
            \item abc
            \begin{itemize}
                \item def
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
    \item bar
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 40):

I recommend the `enumitem` package too, but your task can be done without it, by supplying the `\item` command with its optional argument

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for the \checkmark command 

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\checkmark] foo
    \item[$\times$] bar
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Building on @cmhughes solution, if you have a long list of item , you can define commands as shortcuts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\done}{\item[\checkmark]}
\newcommand{\crossed}{\item[$\times$]}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \done this is done
  \crossed this is still not done
  \crossed this is also not done
  \done but this is
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you need the `enumitem` package then? :) best to keep code samples as minimal as possible :)

Comment: Hmm no actually you don't, somehow I mistakenly assumed that specifying the label after the item definition was an `enumitem` thing, but it is not. Thanks, answer updated.