# Latex enumerate environment I want to enumerate with A.1,A.2,...,A.n. How does one do this?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I am using latex to type up a logical system that has some equations.  The abbreviation for the logical system is DAS.  I would like the equations to be numbered
DAS.1
DAS.2
...
DAS.n

I expected that

```
\begin{enumerate}[{DAS.1}]
    \item
    \item
    ...
   \item
\end{enumerate}
```

would work.  However the output I get is:

D1S.1
D2S.2
...
DnS.n

So I suppose the question could be restated as: how does one control which letter the enumerate environment ... enumerates?  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ah.  I just figured out a hackish way to do it.
use
\begin{enumerate}[\text{DAS}.1]
instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`enumerate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) provides the optional argument functionality to listing environments like `enumerate`. However, to make this work as expected, you need to "shield" the unwanted enumeration from the choices. This is done by putting `DAS` inside braces, and therefore using

```
\begin{enumerate}[{DAS}.1]
```

since in

```
\begin{enumerate}[{DAS.1}]
```

the first available enumerations (albeit grouped) are specified by `A` and `1`, causing the `D1S.1`, `D2S.2`, ... output. That is, `enumerate` identifies two locations to place the enumeration, and sets the enumeration style as the last one encountered (`1`/`\arabic` in this case). Consequently, using

```
\begin{enumerate}[{DAa1S.1}]
```

would yield the enumeration `D111S.1`, `D222S.2`, ..., as is visible from the following minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[{DAS}.1]
  \item stuff
  \item stuff
  \item stuff
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[{DAa1S.1}]
  \item stuff
  \item stuff
  \item stuff
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Similar to the answer provided at [how to represent cross and tick in itemize bullets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48036/how-to-represent-cross-and-tick-in-itemize-bullets/48037#48037_), except this is for `enumerate`.

If you are using [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) you can use `\setlist[enumerate,<n>]{label={DAS.\arabic*}}` to set the enumeration label for the depth of `<n>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={DAS.\arabic*}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={BOOT.\arabic*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item foo 1
    \item foo 2
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item bar 1
        \item bar 2
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can also do it on a per list basis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={DAS.\arabic*}]
    \item foo 1
    \item foo 2
    \begin{enumerate}[label={BOOT.\arabic*}]
        \item bar 1
        \item bar 2
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

A third option would be to define your own list type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{DasList}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[DasList,1]{label={DAS.\arabic*}}

\newlist{BootList}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[BootList,1]{label={BOOT.\arabic*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{DasList}
    \item foo 1
    \item foo 2
    \begin{BootList}
        \item bar 1
        \item bar 2
    \end{BootList}
\end{DasList}
\end{document}
```

---

Without the `enumitem` package you use `\renewcommand{\labelenum<n>}{DAS.\arabic{enum<n>}}` where `<n>` is a roman numeral (`i`, `i`, `iii`, or `iv`) representing the nesting depth of `enumerate`.
 The following yields a similar result to above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{DAS.\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{BOOT.\arabic{enumii}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item foo 1
    \item foo 2
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item bar 1
        \item bar 2
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```