# How to put a tick mark above a letter?

Tags: fonts, graphics, superscripts

I am looking for some way of putting a tick and cross marks above a word or a letter. Something like this[image]

Comment: Refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6195/typeset-an-with-an-above
and
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48036/how-to-represent-cross-and-tick-in-itemize-bullets

Answer (score 5):

For math mode, I'd recommend using `\overset` and the symbols from the `pifont` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

$\overset{\text{\ding{51}}}{A}$
$\overset{\text{\ding{55}}}{B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `stackengine` (I've not searched for the symbols, you'll find them on your own):

[image: stacked]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\stackon{A}{cm}
\stackon{B}{x}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @TeXnician. But it is showing error stackengine.sty not found.

Comment: @Seeker Which TeX distro are you using (TeX Live, MikTeX, ...)? Try using its package manager.

Answer (score 1):

By simple, can use `\mathop` and `\limits` commands, example shown below:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

$\mathop{\mathrm{A}}\limits^\surd$\quad
$\mathop{\mathrm{B}}\limits^\times$
\end{document}
```