# what is the way to make a sqbullet in itemize structure

Tags: itemize

First of all, when I want to use an itemize structure in simply latex document I have not this problem, I mean, I got sqbullet in itemize list. But.. when I inlcude a tikz picture, maybe, I load some packages and then I got dots in itemize list. For this reason, I would like to know how to get sqbullet in this cases. I´ve tried

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item [\sqbullet] A
\end{itemize}
```

or somethin like this [How to change the nested itemize bullet characters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36443/how-to-change-the-nested-itemize-bullet-characters)

But I didn´t. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What packages are you loading? Probably the answer is to load `mathabx` as the last one.

Comment: And anyway it should be `\item[$\sqbullet$] A`

Comment: @karlkoeller Will you create an answer to remove this question from the unanswered list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ **Just to answer the unanswered, converting comments into an answer** ]

Load the `mathabx` package as the last one and remember to use `\sqbullet` in math mode:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item [$\sqbullet$] A
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since loading `mathabx` [changes the appearances of several maths symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165988), you can also just use the relevant parts of the package, as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/3954):

```
% From mathabx.sty.
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathb10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

% From mathabx.dcl.
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqbullet}{1}{mathb}{"0D}
```

and then use `\sqbullet` as proposed in the other answer:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item [$\sqbullet$] A
\end{itemize}
```