# Package mathabx results in tiny square as QED

Tags: amssymb, mathabx

If I use amssymb, the square at the end of the proof would just be in normal size.  But when I use mathabx, the square gets tiny.  Is there any way I can use mathabx and still get the normal square?[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\newenvironment{prf}{\underline{\textbf{Proof:}}}{\hfill $\square$}


\begin{document}

\begin{prf}
This is my proof using mathabx.
\end{prf}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
\let\oldsquare\square
```

*before* loading `mathabx` and then use `\oldsquare` in your definition:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\let\oldsquare\square
\usepackage{mathabx}

\newenvironment{prf}{\underline{\textbf{Proof:}}}{\hfill$\oldsquare$}

\begin{document}

\begin{prf}
This is my proof using mathabx.
\end{prf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `proof` environment from the `amsthm` package doesn't use `\square`, but `\openbox` as the end-mark, so you can define this command as `amsthm.sty` does and use it for your definition:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\newcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
\newenvironment{prf}{\underline{\textbf{Proof:}}}{\hfill$\openbox$}

\begin{document}

\begin{prf}
This is my proof using mathabx.
\end{prf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd suggest you, however, to use the `amsthm` package and its built-in `proof` environment to typeset your proofs. This will give you, amongst other, proper spacing before and after the proofs, proper placement of the end-mark, no indentation for the first line.

In the follwoing example I used both environments for comparison (I suppressed the underlining, since it is not a typographical good practise, but you can add it back of you really need it):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newenvironment{prf}{\underline{\textbf{Proof:}}}{\hfill$\openbox$}
\renewcommand\proofname{\normalfont\bfseries Proof:}

\begin{document}

\begin{prf}
This is my proof using mathabx.
\end{prf}

\begin{proof}
This is my proof using mathabx amnd amsthm.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`mathabx` also offers `\boxvoid`, but this produces a square that it's slightly bigger than the regular `\openbox` command.

Are you sure you want to use `mathabx`? I ask you because the package redefines many math symbols (as you've already experienced). If you are interestef just in a particular symbol from `mathabx`, then [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/3954) shows you how to import the symbol without loading the package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I want to use mathabx because I like its not divide symbol.  It's just right; not to short or too long.

Comment: @pineapple I've edited my answer. Then perhaps you could just import that symbol instead of loading the package and changing many other symbols.

Comment: @pineapple this question is useful if you decide just to import the symbol: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/3954.

Comment: \openbox is perfect. You're right about importing since I only want one symbol from the entire package.

Comment: Wow, oldsquare is great too.