# How to cleanly define nested lists with Latex?

Tags: lists

Surely this is a basic question. I define nested lists using nested \begin{itemize} commands and I'm not satisfied with the default result. The indentation is OK but the marker style is the same for all items regardless of their list level. This looks counter-intuitive to me. Is there a standard (and simple) way to get different markers according to the level of indentation?

I don't feel that defining the marker style manually for each new list is an acceptable solution, nor do I wish to use many additional packages if it can be avoided.

Comment: duplicate: [How to change the nested itemize bullet characters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36443/how-to-change-the-nested-itemize-bullet-characters)

Comment: If you nest `itemize` inside `itemize`, the marker *is* different in the nested list, by default. More information is needed if you don't get different markers.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @egreg so if what I'm seeing isn't the default behavior maybe something in the (rather complicated) [template](http://blog.dorian-depriester.fr/latex/template-these/template-complet-pour-manuscrit-de-these) I'm using is doing it. Anyway, the accepted answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load `enumitem` and set the markers per nesting level in you preamble. For instance:

```
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\textendash}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=*}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=$\circ$}
```

Comment: This is precisely what I wanted, clean and simple. Thank you.