# Inserting a multi level list in latex where the highest level is named year (a numerical digit)

Tags: lists, itemize

I am trying to insert a list into a document in which the highest level has the title 'Year [x]'.

This is my code but it isn't doing quite what I want. I don't want the highest level to be a subsection.

```
\begin{document}

\subsection{Year 1}
\label{subsubsec:subsubsec02}
\begin{itemize}
    \item some text
\end{itemize}
\subsection{Year 2}
\label{subsubsec:subsubsec03}
\begin{itemize}
    \item some more text
\end{itemize}
\subsection{Year 3}
\label{subsubsec:subsubsec04}
\begin{itemize}
    \item even more text
\end{itemize}
\subsection{Year 4}
\label{subsubsec:subsubsec05}
\begin{itemize}
    \item the last bit of text
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Hope you can help

Mensch, the current list looks like this.

0.1 Year 1

• some text

0.2 Year 2

• some more text

0.3 Year 3

• even more text

0.4 Year 4

• the last bit of text

I would like the highest level of the list to have the heading of Year [number] but without it being a subsection that will appear in a contents page

Comment: So don't use `\subsection`, what do you actually want? You can simply nest `itemize` environments e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36443/106162

Comment: Please show an image of your result and mark there what you want to change ...

Comment: My immediate thought was to use a description list. Why is that not a good option?

Comment: Dai Brown, I Followed your advice. The result looks closer to what I want, but I would like the highest-level item to have no bullet point before the heading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use `enumerate` for the years and `itemize` for the *bullet points*:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=Year~\arabic{*}}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=0pt,topsep=0pt}
\item~
  \label{subsubsec:subsubsec02}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item some text
  \end{itemize}
\item~
  \label{subsubsec:subsubsec03}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item some more text
  \end{itemize}
\item~
  \label{subsubsec:subsubsec04}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item even more text
  \end{itemize}
\item~
  \label{subsubsec:subsubsec05}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item the last bit of text
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]